# Ariawan's Ratio: $\mathrm{A}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given
$$\mathrm{A}=\lim_{N \to \infty}\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{\alpha=0}^N \frac{(1 + i\pi)^\alpha}{\alpha!}}{\sum\limits_{\alpha=0}^N \frac{1}{\alpha!}}\right|,$$
then determine the value of $11^\mathrm{A}$?

Comment: Who is Ariawan ?

Comment: @user10676 Truth be told, it's me. Hehehe...

Comment: @TooOldForMath Definetely yes! Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power series on bottom and denominator both converge absolutely to the respective values of the exponential function:

$$e^x = \sum_{\alpha=0}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha!}$$
 Therefore we get 
$$A=\frac{|e^{1+i\pi}|}{|e|}=\frac{|e^1||e^{i\pi}|}{|e|}=1$$
because $e^{i\pi}=-1$.
Therefore

$$11^A=11^1=11$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{\alpha = 0}^N \frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha!} = e^x$$

$$e^{i\pi} = -1$$